# ld can't find library given -L

Tags: makefile, ld

I have an object file `main.o`, and need to link it against a shared library at `./libsvm/libsvm.so.2`. I have the following Makefile but it doesn't work for me. Library path has been specified in `-L./libsvm` but `gcc -lsvm` still can't find the shared library (`libsvm.so.2`).

This is my Makefile:

```
CC      = g++ -g
CFLAGS  = -Wall
HEADERS = -I./libsvm
OBJ     = main.o
LIBS    = -L./libsvm

all: lib $(OBJ)
     $(CC) $(LIBS) -lsvm $(OBJ) -o main

%.o: %.c
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(HEADERS) -c -o $@ $<

lib:
     cd libsvm; make
```

It just works if link them directly, as in

```
ld main.o libsvm/libsvm.so.2 -o main
```

I wonder what's wrong in the Makefile. Error message is the following

```
g++ -g -L./libsvm -lsvm main.o -o main 
ld: library not found for -lsvm 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) 
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: "can't find the shared library" which errors do you get?

Comment: Did you try to make a symbolic link to libsvm.so?

Comment: You aren't asking make to run `ld main.o libsvm/libsvm.so.2 -o main` you are asking it to run something entirely different. The argument to `-l` can be a full path or it can be a library name `-lsvm` for `libsvm.so`.

Comment: @EtanReisner But my way should work, why not?

Comment: `cc -L/usr/local/lib -lsvm main.o -o main` that's not a recipe coming from your makefile. Is `libsvm.o` in `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: seems a bit mixed up: you compile using `g++` but link using `gcc` which turns out to be `clang`?

Comment: You need to figure out why make isn't using your rules (or show us the actual makefile you are using) before we can begin to help you. You also need to know where the library you are trying to link to actually lives.

Comment: @EtanReisner Oh sorry, please see my latest update. I modified the `Makefile` after posting this question so the error was not relevant.

Comment: @m.s. I changed gcc to g++ but the problem remains. I'm using g++ comes with Mac OS which is implemented as a front-end of clang.

Comment: `-lname` looks for `libname.so` not `libname.so.2` or `libname.so.0.2` or anything else. So you need to have that symlink available or link to the file by path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-lsvm means use the file svm.so

But your library file has name svm.so.2. ([Version 2](https://superuser.com/questions/299009/what-do-the-number-suffixes-in-linux-dynamic-libraries-mean))

So either rename or make a symbolic link with

```
ln -s svm.so.2 svm.so
```

Now the makefile should work.

Comment: Thanks. This solves my problem. As a follow up question, what's the point of having different versions of shared libraries but a single `libsvm.so`?

Comment: Indeed a good question! You should ask it on SO as a separate question. Honestly, no idea :-) These are only my interpretation: If you look in various lib-directories, you'll se for the most (all?) cases .so and .so.X.Y files sym-linked. As long as the newer versions are backward compatible, it's ok. But it still leaves the possibility to use an older library, if some packages would depend on it.